# Powershell replace "string:stuff" to "string"

Tags: powershell, replace

Hi there I am having trouble with a simple replace command in Powershell. What i am looking to do is to replace "STRINGNO:########" (# are not known) to "STRINGNO:" i was using something along the lines of

```
$a="STRINGNO:#######"
$a.replace("STRINGNO:*", "STRINGNO:")
```

but that doesn't work. I've also tried

```
$a -replace 'STRINGNO:*', 'STRINGNO:'
```

Comment: `STRINGNO:*` is a regular expression that matches `STRINGNO` and then an arbitrary number of `:` characters. You probably meant to write `STRINGNO:.*`

Comment: The [`-replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) operator does [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) matching, not [wildcard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088.aspx) matching, so it's `.*`, not just `*`.

Comment: The [System.String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method you used looks for a string containing the exact characters and replaces them with another set of characters. There is no support for pattern matching. If you want pattern matching use the powershell -replace and regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you Jacob got the answer by using -replace with 'STRINGNO:.*' didn't know about .*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring closure to this question with an idiomatic PowerShell solution:

```
> 'STRINGNO:#######' -replace '(STRINGNO:).*', '$1'
STRINGNO:
```

- `'(STRINGNO:).*'` is a *regular expression* - which is what `-replace` expects as its first operand - that matches any line that contains literal `STRINGNO:` - enclosed in `(...)` to form a *capture group* - followed by any number of characters (`.*`) - in other words: it matches (part of) a string that contains literal `STRINGNO:`, starting with that string, *through the end of the line*.
- `$1` then replaces what the regex matched - *if* it matched - with what the regex' first capture group (`$1`) matched - which is `STRINGNO:` in the case at hand.